# Lines Shapes and Shananagins

Tags: c#, wpf

So, Basically I'm trying to draw a line between the center of 2 ellipses

And I think this should do it:

```
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;     
myPath.StrokeThickness = 4;
myPath.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
myPath.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
EllipseGeometry myEllipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();
myEllipseGeometry.Center = new System.Windows.Point((xQuard * 10) + 100, yQuard * 10);
myEllipseGeometry.RadiusX = 2;
myEllipseGeometry.RadiusY = 2;
myPath.Data = myEllipseGeometry;
GraphPanel.Children.Add(myPath);

//if it's not the first point...
if (prevA != 0.0)
{
Path iLine = new Path();
iLine.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
iLine.StrokeThickness = 4;
iLine.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
myPath.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
LineGeometry iLineGeometry = new LineGeometry();

iLineGeometry.StartPoint = myEllipseGeometry.Center;

iLineGeometry.EndPoint = new System.Windows.Point(prevA, prevB);

iLine.Data = iLineGeometry;
GraphPanel.Children.Add(iLine);

}

//Set the previous point(s)
prevA = (xQuard * 10) + 100;
prevB = yQuard * 10;
```

---

Now as you can see, I've set the Line's StartPoint = to the first ellipse start point

And Yet....
[image]

Why is the Line's start point in the picture not the center of the point on the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `iLine.VerticalAlignment` instead of `myPath.VerticalAlignment` the second time, right?